# JPA / EclipseLink - create script source with one SQL statement taking multiple lines

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, newline, ddl, persistence.xml

I want to let the persistence provider (EclipseLink 2.5.0) automatically create the tables in the, already existing, database by using the persistence unit property "javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" and a valid SQL-DDL-script.

**persistence.xml:**

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="data/ddl.sql"/>
```

**ddl.sql:**

```
USE myDatabase;

CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    myColumn VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

But I got the following error:

```
[EL Warning]: 2014-02-12 13:31:44.778--ServerSession(768298666)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: CREATE TABLE MyTable (
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE MyTable (")
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:895)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:957)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:630)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:271)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3207)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1730)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeNonSelectingCall(AbstractSession.java:1499)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeNonSelectingSQL(AbstractSession.java:1517)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeSourceScriptToDatabase(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:4065)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDL(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:3910)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.writeDDL(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:3783)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:724)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:527)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:140)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:177)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
        at nl.tent.competent.data.access.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:885)
        ... 29 more
```

It seems that the carriage return line feed (newline) is the problem. And if I change the SQL-DDL-script, so that one SQL-statement only takes one line, everything is working fine.

**adjusted ddl.sql:**

```
USE myDatabase;

CREATE TABLE MyTable (id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, myColumn VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

But I don't want to reformat my SQL-DDL-script for readability. Please help!

Comment: If anyone is interested, I created an issue in the payara issue tracker (Payara is a version derived from glassfish with optional support).

https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/874

Comment: 2018. Still no fix.

Answer (score 3):

If someone still faces this problem, it can be solved by adding following parameter (found [here](https://softwarecave.org/2017/02/12/database-schema-creation-in-jpa-using-sql-scripts/)):

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor" value="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor" />
```

Comment: In Hibernate 6, the relevant class is now `org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.script.MultiLineSqlScriptExtractor`.