# JPA 2.1 derby/javadb create script with line breaks will not run

Tags: java, sql, jpa, derby, jpa-2.1

Please have a look on my create script.

My goal is to controll the creation of the schema by script and let the dropping be handled by the metadata stuff.

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />

<property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="DERBY" />
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" />

<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />

<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.script.action" value="create" />
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="script" />
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source"
       value="file:/home/kevin/workspace_pluginDev/zvagent/src/main/resources/META-INF/sql/create_tables.ddl" />
<property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
       value="file:/home/kevin/workspace_pluginDev/zvagent/src/main/resources/META-INF/sql/load_stammdaten.sql" />
```

The create script will be executed but fails on the end of the first line. It seems like the create script is executed line wise and not statement by statement:

**The create script**

I tested this script successfully on the same DB connection inside Eclipse using a SQL-Scrapbook editor.

```
CREATE TABLE TABELLENNAME (
    "BESCHREIBUNG"      VARCHAR(255),
    "ID"                BIGINT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "LASTUPDATE"        BIGINT,
    "SONSTIGES"         VARCHAR(255),
);
```

But when called from JPA this happens:

**Log/Error messages from the DB**

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.167--ServerSession(194685468)--Connection(1337157493)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--CREATE TABLE TABELLENNAME (
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.17--ServerSession(194685468)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--VALUES(1)
[EL Warning]: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.172--ServerSession(194685468)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntaxfehler: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 27.
Error Code: 0
Call: CREATE TABLE TABELLENNAME (
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE TABELLENNAME (")
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.172--ServerSession(194685468)--Connection(1337157493)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--"BESCHREIBUNG"      VARCHAR(255),
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.179--ServerSession(194685468)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--VALUES(1)
[EL Warning]: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.181--ServerSession(194685468)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntaxfehler: Encountered "\"BESCHREIBUNG\"" at line 1, column 1.
Error Code: 0
Call: "BESCHREIBUNG"        VARCHAR(255),
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql=""BESCHREIBUNG"      VARCHAR(255),")
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.182--ServerSession(194685468)--Connection(1337157493)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--"ID"                BIGINT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.184--ServerSession(194685468)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--VALUES(1)
[EL Warning]: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.186--ServerSession(194685468)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntaxfehler: Encountered "\"ID\"" at line 1, column 1.
Error Code: 0
Call: "ID"              BIGINT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql=""ID"                BIGINT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,")
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.193--ServerSession(194685468)--Connection(1337157493)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--"LASTUPDATE"        BIGINT,
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.196--ServerSession(194685468)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--VALUES(1)
[EL Warning]: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.198--ServerSession(194685468)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntaxfehler: Encountered "\"LASTUPDATE\"" at line 1, column 1.
Error Code: 0
Call: "LASTUPDATE"      BIGINT,
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql=""LASTUPDATE"        BIGINT,")
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.198--ServerSession(194685468)--Connection(1337157493)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--"SONSTIGES"         VARCHAR(255),
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.202--ServerSession(194685468)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--VALUES(1)
[EL Warning]: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.203--ServerSession(194685468)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntaxfehler: Encountered "\"SONSTIGES\"" at line 1, column 1.
Error Code: 0
Call: "SONSTIGES"       VARCHAR(255),
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql=""SONSTIGES"         VARCHAR(255),")
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.204--ServerSession(194685468)--Connection(1337157493)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--);
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.206--ServerSession(194685468)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--VALUES(1)
[EL Warning]: 2014-03-09 13:45:44.208--ServerSession(194685468)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntaxfehler: Encountered ")" at line 1, column 1.
Error Code: 0
Call: );
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql=");")
```

**Q:** Is there a way to format the create scripts human readable but at the same time executable as create script?

Comment: Seems like line breaks are indeed not working...: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/496133/1076128/#msg_1076128
Is there a spec for this behavior?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729097/jpa-eclipselink-create-script-source-with-one-sql-statement-taking-multiple